# Commit to git after switching to workspace and adding CocoaPods library

Tags: cocoapods, atlassian-sourcetree, xcode-workspace

I'm a Cocoapods newbie, so I have a basic question.

After adding cocoa pods to my project, a workspace file is generated, and from now on I must to use this file to open and work on the project.

Currently my project is stored in an Git.

To enable my working partners to work with me on the project, I need to commit the `.workspace` file so they to can open and work on the project too.  But unfortunately, after creating the workspace by the cocoa pods, my Git client (Source tree) doesn't recognise the `.workspace` file as a added file.

Is there something I'm missing?  Do have to commit my `.workspace` file in order to enable my code partners to work on the project with the Cocoapods added library? or maybe its a Xcode setup in order for the Git to recognise the new workspace?

any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
git add --all
git commit
```

And then checking if the file was added???